# ASP.NET MVC3 How to better secure action which return Json Result

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action which rerun json result based on subscription id and users who subscribed to that content.

So if user subscribed for Subscription 1 he well be able to get data only for Subscription 1, if user subscribed for Subscription 2 he well be able to get data for that. If he subscribed for 1 and 2 so he will be able to get related content 1 and 2 and so on.

So the question is controller secured from unauthorized requests and users who does not have permissions to unsubscribed content?

All right what i can do so:

1) I may secure my controller with [Authorize] attribute, it will prevent unauthorized requests to controller.
2) On each request i will be checking user name and is that user really allowed to get requested content.

So am i secured after all then?

How difficult it will be to get access to unsubscribed content for authorized users and  how difficult it will be to steal by not authorized users after i implement two steps above? Should i think of something else to better secure the content/website?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you use the Authorize Attribute and/or the IsInRole method, you should be fine from an Authorization stance. You need to make sure your Authentication is well secured too.

For instance: 
Authentication using OpenID providers and rely parties would satisfy Authentiation. I use DotNetOpenAuth for this...

Authorization would be provided by something like a custom made grouping system. I've used basic database relationships to match up with the identity provided by openID.

In addition to those you will need to secure the pipe from MITM attacks and sniffing. So you could look at claims based security and some tricks used to avoid MITM attacks with timestamps.

Then, of course, put it all over https.

Just my two cents. I hope it helps a little. Security is a very wide and deep topic, so I'm only offering suggestions of where to look. My way will most certainly not be the best.